# vectorize a search function matlab

Tags: matlab, search, find

looking for an efficient way to vectorize a search

say A is 2 by 4 array

```
 x      y     z     a
.2      0.97  34.2  4.5
```

and B is a 1 by 1000 array

```
a x x x x y y y z z a .........
```

How do I get the corresponding row 2 values of A for array B. Looking for a vectorized efficient solution, I have an if loop that works but not efficient.

Thanks

I currently have

```
A(2,A(1,:)==B(:))
```

but this doesn't work as both arrays have different sizes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second output from the `ismember` function, like this:

```
%Setup
A = [24 25 26 1; 0.2 0.97 34.2 4.5]
B = [1 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 26 26 1];

%Use ismember to get matching indexes
[~, ixs] = ismember(B, A(1,:))

%Use indexes to get desired result
out = A(2,ixs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, just wondering if I could get a faster implementation. This arrays are in orders 10^6.